# How to get results from listdata.svc from a certain folder

Tags: web-services, linq, ajax, listdata.svc

I'm looking to get a certain set of data from my list using the listdata.svc service with AJAX. The problem is inside the list I have folders, and I'd like to only receive elements inside a certain folder.

The list looks like this:

```
myList //list
    --> Folder001 //folder
        --> Item01 //listitem
        --> Item02 //listitem
        --> Item03 //listitem
    --> Folder002 //folder
        --> Item01 //listitem
        --> Item02 //listitem
```

So far I've found that I can add the attribute `?$filter=` to the address but can't figure out how to use it to my advantage.

I see that each element has a "Path" value which ends with the folder. How would I go about only retreiving those entries from list whose "Path" attribute ends with a certain value, say "Folder0001"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $filter query string and a property called "Path" like

```
/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/myList()?$filter=endswith(Path, 'Folder001')
```

to get only the items from the Folder001

Comment: Glad we found a solution. It was an interesting question.